# Fastest way to count from a table where a certain field exists in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been scratching my head on this for hours now. I am using PHP and MySQLi. I have two tables: table1 and table2. The table1 table has:

```
uid
name
phoneNumber
```

And the table2 table has

```
id
phoneNumber
```

The registered table contains more than 100,000 entries as compared to the users table with about 1000 entries. I am looking for an efficient query to scan through table2 and count the number of records that have the phoneNumber value present in table1 (phoneNumber).

I will really appreciate any help or direction in solving this query problem

Regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(t2.id) 
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE exists (select t1.* FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.phoneNumber = t2.phoneNumber)
GROUP BY t2.phoneNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you give us a closer explanation how your tables look like?

You need to have one foreign key for this to be possible (pretty much means an id or key that is the same in both tables so they can be LEFT JOIN'ed by that column), then a little WHERE t2.col IS NOT NULL and you are done but I cannot give you a sample query until I am sure how your db structure really looks like because field "phoneNumber" looks somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
#1:
select count(*)  
from table1 as t1
where exists
 ( select *
   from table2 as t2 
   where t1.phoneNumber = t2.phoneNumber) 

#2:
select count(*)
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
 on t1.phoneNumber = t2.phoneNumber

#3:
select count(*)  
from table1 as t1
where phoneNumber in
 ( select phoneNumber
   from table2 as t2 )
```

Comment: thanks so much @dnoeth, these three work really well, i would like to ask, which one would be faster/more efficient in your view?

Comment: Other DBMSes would create exactly the same plan for all three version. But MySQL's optimizer is probably not that good, I assume the join might be best.  Of course you should run all three and check performance.